# Plotting data from apache pig via matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, streaming, apache-pig

So I'm trying to plot some data through apache pig using python/matplotlib.

Specifically, I'd like to read and process the data using pig, then stream it through a plotting script written in python.

I've been using the plotting script for a while outside of apache pig without incident so I'm fairly certain that isn't the problem, but I can post it if someone wants me to.

Here's my pig script right now.

```
%default BINSIZE 5.0

/* functions */
define plot `test_plot.py -f output_image.png` ship('/tank/user/eric/dev/pig/test_plot.py');

/* load the data */
cd /scratch;
VALUE = load 'test_data.txt' as (x_val:double);

/* bin the data */
BINNED_VAL = foreach VALUE
         generate (double)((int)( x_val / $BINSIZE )) * $BINSIZE;

/* make a histogram */
COUNTED = group BINNED_VAL by $0;
HIST = foreach COUNTED generate group, COUNT(BINNED_VAL);

A = stream HIST through plot;

dump A;
```

The `-f` flag to test_plot.py specifies the output file. The script reads from stdin but doesn't write to stdout, so A never actually gets set to anything, meaning `dump A` doesn't actually do anything. (and indeed throws an error).

Here's the contents of test_data.txt:

```
5
5
6
6.5
8
12
28
25
25
25
26
29
32
35
```

Here's the error message I'm getting:

```
2014-07-07 12:49:30,973 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - ERROR 2090: Received Error while processing the reduce plan: 'test_plot.py (stdin-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming/stdout-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming)' failed with exit status: 1
2014-07-07 12:49:30,973 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
2014-07-07 12:49:30,974 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics: 

HadoopVersion   PigVersion      UserId  StartedAt       FinishedAt      Features
2.4.0.2.1.2.1-471       0.12.1.2.1.2.1-471      eric    2014-07-07 12:48:57  2014-07-07 12:49:30      GROUP_BY,STREAMING

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_1404713698289_0021  A,BINNED_VAL,COUNTED,HIST,VALUE GROUP_BY,STREAMING,COMBINER   Message: Job failed!    hdfs://hypno.st.hmc.edu:8020/tmp/temp-2122498041/tmp461187682,

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "hdfs://hypno.st.hmc.edu:8020/scratch/test_data.txt"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "hdfs://hypno.st.hmc.edu:8020/tmp/temp-2122498041/tmp461187682"

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_1404713698289_0021


2014-07-07 12:49:30,974 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Failed!
2014-07-07 12:49:30,986 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2090: Received Error while processing the reduce plan: 'test_plot.py (stdin-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming/stdout-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming)' failed with exit status: 1
Details at logfile: /tank/user/eric/dev/pig/pig_1404762535492.log
```

And here's the output logfile:

```
Backend error message
---------------------
AttemptID:attempt_1404713698289_0021_m_000000_0 Info:Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143

Backend error message
---------------------
AttemptID:attempt_1404713698289_0021_r_000000_0 Info:Error: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2090: Received Error while processing the reduce plan: 'test_plot.py (stdin-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming/stdout-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming)' failed with exit status: 1
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.runPipeline(PigGenericMapReduce.java:496)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.cleanup(PigGenericMapReduce.java:522)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:179)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:627)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1557)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)

Backend error message
---------------------
AttemptID:attempt_1404713698289_0021_r_000000_0 Info:Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143

Backend error message
---------------------
AttemptID:attempt_1404713698289_0021_r_000000_1 Info:Error: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2090: Received Error while processing the reduce plan: 'test_plot.py (stdin-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming/stdout-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming)' failed with exit status: 1
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.runPipeline(PigGenericMapReduce.java:496)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.cleanup(PigGenericMapReduce.java:522)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:179)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:627)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1557)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)

Backend error message
---------------------
AttemptID:attempt_1404713698289_0021_r_000000_1 Info:Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143

Backend error message
---------------------
AttemptID:attempt_1404713698289_0021_r_000000_2 Info:Error: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2090: Received Error while processing the reduce plan: 'test_plot.py (stdin-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming/stdout-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming)' failed with exit status: 1
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.runPipeline(PigGenericMapReduce.java:496)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.cleanup(PigGenericMapReduce.java:522)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:179)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:627)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1557)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)

Backend error message
---------------------
AttemptID:attempt_1404713698289_0021_r_000000_2 Info:Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143

Backend error message
---------------------
AttemptID:attempt_1404713698289_0021_r_000000_3 Info:Error: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2090: Received Error while processing the reduce plan: 'test_plot.py (stdin-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming/stdout-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming)' failed with exit status: 1
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.runPipeline(PigGenericMapReduce.java:496)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.cleanup(PigGenericMapReduce.java:522)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:179)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:627)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1557)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)

Error message from task (reduce) task_1404713698289_0021_r_000000
-----------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR 2090: Received Error while processing the reduce plan: 'test_plot.py (stdin-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming/stdout-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming)' failed with exit status: 1

org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2090: Received Error while processing the reduce plan: 'test_plot.py (stdin-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming/stdout-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming)' failed with exit status: 1
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.runPipeline(PigGenericMapReduce.java:496)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.cleanup(PigGenericMapReduce.java:522)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:179)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:627)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1557)
================================================================================
Error message from task (reduce) task_1404713698289_0021_r_000000
-----------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR 2090: Received Error while processing the reduce plan: 'test_plot.py (stdin-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming/stdout-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming)' failed with exit status: 1

org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2090: Received Error while processing the reduce plan: 'test_plot.py (stdin-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming/stdout-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming)' failed with exit status: 1
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.runPipeline(PigGenericMapReduce.java:496)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.cleanup(PigGenericMapReduce.java:522)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:179)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:627)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1557)
================================================================================
Error message from task (reduce) task_1404713698289_0021_r_000000
-----------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR 2090: Received Error while processing the reduce plan: 'test_plot.py (stdin-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming/stdout-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming)' failed with exit status: 1

org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2090: Received Error while processing the reduce plan: 'test_plot.py (stdin-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming/stdout-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming)' failed with exit status: 1
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.runPipeline(PigGenericMapReduce.java:496)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.cleanup(PigGenericMapReduce.java:522)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:179)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:627)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1557)
================================================================================
Error message from task (reduce) task_1404713698289_0021_r_000000
-----------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR 2090: Received Error while processing the reduce plan: 'test_plot.py (stdin-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming/stdout-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming)' failed with exit status: 1

org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2090: Received Error while processing the reduce plan: 'test_plot.py (stdin-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming/stdout-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming)' failed with exit status: 1
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.runPipeline(PigGenericMapReduce.java:496)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.cleanup(PigGenericMapReduce.java:522)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:179)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:627)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1557)
================================================================================
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 2090: Received Error while processing the reduce plan: 'test_plot.py (stdin-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming/stdout-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming)' failed with exit status: 1

org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias A. Backend error : Received Error while processing the reduce plan: 'test_plot.py (stdin-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming/stdout-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming)' failed with exit status: 1
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:872)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:774)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:372)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:198)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:173)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:607)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2090: Received Error while processing the reduce plan: 'test_plot.py (stdin-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming/stdout-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming)' failed with exit status: 1
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.runPipeline(PigGenericMapReduce.java:496)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.cleanup(PigGenericMapReduce.java:522)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:179)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:627)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1557)
================================================================================
```

My pig version is `Apache Pig version 0.12.1.2.1.2.1-471` and I'm using `Python 2.6.6`.

I'm also pretty new to pig so I apologize if I'm missing something dumb.

I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction. :)

Comment: Is Python installed on all your nodes? I'd recommend starting with local mode and get that working first. Also, I'm not sure if dumping a PNG file is going to work...

Comment: Yes, this is a single node / testing installation with python 2.6.6 installed.

I'm also not trying to dump a PNG, I'm trying to write a png to the local filesystem from within the python script. The dump might be part of my problem because it's actually dumping nothing. Is there a way to end a script without dumping?

Comment: Could you post your python script? Maybe start with a really simple python script that just writes one line to stdout to find out where the error is

Comment: By the way, pig will add brackets to your data, can your python script cope with that?